# WhatsApp password not generated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, whatsapp

While trying to generate the password I get the below error

**"Could not generate password"**

Please find my below code

```
if (WhatsAppApi.Register.WhatsRegisterV2.RequestCode(txtPhoneNumber.Text, out password, "sms"))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        Save();
    else
    {
        grbRequestCode.Enabled = false;
        grbConfirmCode.Enabled = true;
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not generate password.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Please let me know why I get this error.

Comment: https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API-NET/blob/master/WhatsAppApi/Register/WhatsRegisterV2.cs#L40 Maybe this can help you

Comment: @CallumLinington I have tried this but no luck...
Even I tried this with WART tool available at github but still I get the same error..... :(

Comment: @mayankBhuvnesh any luck figuring out the api?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find out any solutions?